# $\frac{4}{\pi^{2}}\sum_{k~=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k}\le\|D_{N}\|_{L^{1}({\bf T})}\le3~-\frac{2}{\pi}+\frac{4}{\pi^{2}}\sum_{k~=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $D_{N}(t)=\frac{\sin((2N+1)\pi t)}{\sin(\pi t)}$ be defined on ${\bf T}={\bf R}/{\bf Z}~=[0,1]$ , which is the so-called Dirichlet kernel  . Prove that for each integer $N>0~$ we have 
$$\frac{4}{\pi^{2}}\sum_{k~=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k}\le\|D_{N}\|_{L^{1}({\bf T})}\le3~-\frac{2}{\pi}+\frac{4}{\pi^{2}}\sum_{k~=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k}$$

Here's my attempt for the first inequality but I stuck with the latter inequality :

\begin{align}
\|D_{N}\|_{L^{1}(\bf T)}&=\int_{0}^{1}\bigg|\frac{\sin((2N+1)\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}\bigg|~dx\\
&=\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg|\frac{\sin((2N+1)\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}\bigg|~dx\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg|\frac{\sin((2N+1)\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}\bigg|~dx\\
&=2\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\int_{\frac{k}{2N+1}}^{\frac{k+1}{2N+1}}~\bigg|\frac{\sin((2N+1)\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}\bigg|~dx+\int_{\frac{N}{2N+1}}^{\frac{1}{2}}~\bigg|\frac{\sin((2N+1)\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}\bigg|~dx\bigg)\\
&\geq2\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\int_{\frac{k}{2N+1}}^{\frac{k+1}{2N+1}}~\bigg|\frac{\sin((2N+1)\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}\bigg|~dx\\
&\geq2\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\int_{\frac{k}{2N+1}}^{\frac{k+1}{2N+1}}~\frac{|\sin((2N+1)\pi x)|}{\pi x}~dx\\
&\geq2\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\int_{\frac{k}{2N+1}}^{\frac{k+1}{2N+1}}~\frac{2N+1}{(k+1)\pi}|\sin((2N+1)\pi x)|~dx\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{1}{(k+1)\pi^{2}}|\sin x|~dx\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{(k+1)\pi^{2}}|\sin x|~dx\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^{n}~\frac{1}{k\pi^{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi}~\sin x~dx\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k}
\end{align}

For the second inequality I tried but fail . Any comments or valuable suggestions I will be grateful .

Answer (score 1):

For the second part , we have this following :
\begin{align}
\|D\|_{L^{1}({\bf T})}&=2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg|\frac{\sin((2N+1)\pi x)}{\sin \pi x}\bigg|~dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{\pi}\bigg|\frac{\sin((2N+1) x)}{\sin x}\bigg|~dx\\
&=\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{\pi}|\sin((2N+1) x)|\bigg(\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{x}\bigg)~dx}_{\color{blue}{(1)}}~+\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{|\sin((2N+1)x)|}{x}~dx}_{\color{blue}{(2)}}
\end{align}

**We now estimate the blue one $\color{blue}{(1)}$ :**

Firstly , note that $0\le\big(\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{x}\big)\le1-\frac{2}{\pi}~$for $x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2}]~.$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{\pi}|\sin((2N+1)x)|\bigg(\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{x}\bigg)~dx&\le\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{\pi}\bigg(\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{x}\bigg)~dx\\
&\le\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{\pi}\bigg(1-\frac{2}{\pi}\bigg)~dx\\
&=1-\frac{2}{\pi} 
\end{align}

**For the latter one $\color{blue}{(2)}~:$**
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{|\sin ((2N+1)x)|}{x}~dx
&=\bigg(\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2N+1}}}_{\color{blue}{(3)}}+\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{\frac{k\pi}{2N+1}}^{\frac{(k+1)\pi}{2N+1}}}_{\color{blue}{(4)}}+\underbrace{\int_{\frac{N\pi}{2N+1}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}}_{\color{blue}{(5)}}~\bigg)\frac{2|\sin ((2N+1)x)|}{\pi x}dx
\end{align}
For $\color{blue}{(3)}~:$

$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2N+1}}\frac{|\sin ((2N+1)x)|}{x}dx\le\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2N+1}}\frac{(2N+1)x}{x}~dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\pi=2$$
For $\color{blue}{(4)}~:$
\begin{align}
\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{\frac{k\pi}{2N+1}}^{\frac{(k+1)\pi}{2N+1}}\frac{|\sin ((2N+1)x)|}{x}~dx&\le\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{\frac{k\pi}{2N+1}}^{\frac{(k+1)\pi}{2N+1}}~\frac{2N+1}{k\pi}~|\sin((2N+1)x)|~dx\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{1}{k\pi}|\sin x|~dx\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{k\pi}|\sin x|~dx\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{2}{k\pi}\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{k}\\
\end{align}
For $\color{blue}{(5)}~:$
\begin{align}
\int_{\frac{N\pi}{2N+1}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2|\sin ((2N+1)x)|}{\pi x}dx&\le\int_{\frac{N\pi}{2N+1}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{2N+1}{N\pi}|\sin((2N+1)x)|~dx\\
&=\frac{2}{N\pi^{2}}\int_{\frac{N\pi}{2N+1}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(2N+1)|\sin((2N+1)x)|~dx\\
&=\frac{2}{N\pi^{2}}\int_{N\pi}^{(N+\frac{1}{2})\pi}~|\sin x|~dx\\
&\le\frac{2}{N\pi^{2}}\int_{N\pi}^{(N+1)\pi}~|\sin x|~dx\\
&=\frac{2}{N\pi^{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi}~|\sin x|~dx\\
&=\frac{4}{N\pi^{2}}
\end{align}

Combine  $\color{blue}{(3)}$ , $\color{blue}{(4)}$ and $\color{blue}{(5)}$ to get 
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{|\sin ((2N+1)x)|}{x}~dx&\le2+\frac{4}{\pi^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{k}+\frac{4}{N\pi^{2}}\\
&=2+\frac{4}{\pi^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k}\color{blue}{~~-(6)}
\end{align}
Finally, we associate the results $\color{blue}{(1)}$ and $\color{blue}{(6)}$ to obtain our desired consequence , 
\begin{align}
\|D\|_{L^{1}({\bf T})}&=2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg|\frac{\sin((2N+1)\pi x)}{\sin \pi x}\bigg|~dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{2}{\pi}\bigg|\frac{\sin((2N+1) x)}{\sin x}\bigg|~dx\\
&\le\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{\pi}|\sin((2N+1)x)|\bigg(\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{x}\bigg)~dx+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{|\sin ((2N+1)x)|}{x}~dx\\
&\le(1-\frac{2}{\pi})+\bigg(2+\frac{4}{\pi^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k}\bigg)\\
&=3-\frac{2}{\pi}+\frac{4}{\pi^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k}
\end{align}